# Unity3D: 'Physics' does not contain a definition for 'Raycast'

Tags: c#, unity, scripting

I'm a complete beginner in Unity 3D, and I'm following a video training. In the video the instructor uses the following code to open a door using raycast:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class HelloRaycasting : MonoBehaviour {

    bool doorClosed = true;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        Vector3 backward = new Vector3 ( 0, 0, -1);
        Vector3 origin = this.gameObject.transform.position;

        if (Physics.Raycast( origin, backward, 1f) && doorClosed) {
            doorClosed = false;
            GameObject.Find ("Left_Quad").transform.Translate ( new Vector3(-.8f, 0, 0));
            GameObject.Find ("Right_Quad").transform.Translate ( new Vector3(.8f, 0, 0));
        }   
    }
}
```

It works just fine for him. But when I try to run this on my computer I get this error:

> Assets/HelloRaycasting.cs(20,29): error CS0117: 'Physics' does not
>   contain a definition for 'Raycast'

In the end I'm not able to access none of the [properties and methods](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.html) of the Physics class.

I'm using Unity 5.3.2f1 (64-bit). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd guess you made your own class or imported some other class named `Physics`. Try fully qualifying it `UnityEngine.Physics.Raycast`.

Alternatively, you can make sure you make a clean build to ensure there's nothing left over that's messing up your build.

Comment: You're correct. I had some draft script named as Physics, just deleted it and problem solved. Thank you.